# Using syntastic plugin with vim in Windows 8.0 Powershell

Tags: powershell, vim, plugins, go, syntastic

I've recently been using the Windows 8.0 Powershell package manager program called "scoop" (see https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop for more details), which is based off of Mac's HomeBrew.  I have installed Vim (7.4) with this tool.  I am trying to make use of a vim syntax highlighting plugin called syntastic (see https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic), since vim as it is currently installed on my machine does not seem to recognize Go language syntax.  However, I am not sure where to start in terms of integrating this plugin with Vim.  Scoop installs Vim with a plugin sub directory...the directory path on my computer would be:

~\AppData\Local\scoop\apps\vim\7.4\plugin

I've tried cloning the syntastic repository into the plugin directory, but the Go syntax is still not recognized.

I do not want to install vim as a separate IDE, because I prefer working within the shell (the same way vim integrates with a Cygwin terminal).  Is there possibly another plugin I should try using all together?

Thank you very much for any info/ time put into answering this question.

Comment: Syntastic is about syntax checking, not syntax highlighting.  For syntax highlighting (and other Go-related goodies) use [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go).

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Commentor Icdc047 threw me in the right direction.
see: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go

Comment: Whatever, just please don't conflate my (nick)name with AC/DC.  For one, I suspect rather few AC/DC members have heard of Vim. :)